# Replace div with another div when resizing window

Tags: jquery, css, html

I Have this HTML code:

```
<div id="div_top"></div>
<div id="div_bottom"></div>
```

Only on Mobile website or when I resize the window I want `div2` before  `div1`.

So I use

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 480){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#div_bottom').insertBefore('#div_top');
    });

    jQuery(document).resize(function(){
        jQuery('#div_bottom').insertBefore('#div_top');
    });
}
```

Load function works well, but resize not.

Is there a jQuery of CSS solution for this problem?

Comment: so what your saying is that this code works correctly when it loads but when you resize the window it doesnt?

Comment: Indeed!. It works correctly when it loads but doesn't when I resize the window.

Comment: check out the fiddle i posted in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 480) {
        $("div#div_bottom").insertBefore("div#div_top");
    }
});
```

Should do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.resize()` on the `window` object instead of `document`.

src: http://api.jquery.com/resize/#comment-34139342

Answer (score 0):

the `$(window).resize(function() {...});` method should work.. check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly96f/22/)

dont forget you need a `$(document).read(function() {});` also. the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly96f/22/) already has this method implemented, you just cant see it. (check the far left column and there is a check saying that is method is already implemented)